joining two dataframes on column value and column name
I have two dataframes that I am trying to join in some way to produce a third dataframe.
I am doing this in python.
df1:



Date
A
B
C




27/04/2023 00:00
55.6637
0.32194
0.145006


28/04/2023 00:00
57.1432
0.327949
0.14712


29/04/2023 00:00
57.3842
0.322167
0.146119


30/04/2023 00:00
57.1259
0.320318
0.145881



df2:



Date
change
Ticker




27/04/2023 00:00
0.1
A


28/04/2023 00:00
-0.1
A


29/04/2023 00:00
0.2
A


30/04/2023 00:00
-0.2
A


27/04/2023 00:00
0.3
B


28/04/2023 00:00
-0.3
B


29/04/2023 00:00
0.4
B


30/04/2023 00:00
-0.4
B


27/04/2023 00:00
0.5
C


28/04/2023 00:00
-0.5
C


29/04/2023 00:00
0.6
C


30/04/2023 00:00
-0.6
C



I want to join the two dataframes so that the value in df1 are joined to df2 on Date and where the ticker in df2 is equal to the column name in df1.
The result should look like this:



Date
change
Ticker
Px




27/04/2023 00:00
0.1
A
55.6637


28/04/2023 00:00
-0.1
A
57.1432


29/04/2023 00:00
0.2
A
57.3842


30/04/2023 00:00
-0.2
A
57.1259


27/04/2023 00:00
0.3
B
0.32194


28/04/2023 00:00
-0.3
B
0.327949


29/04/2023 00:00
0.4
B
0.322167


30/04/2023 00:00
-0.4
B
0.320318


27/04/2023 00:00
0.5
C
0.145006


28/04/2023 00:00
-0.5
C
0.14712


29/04/2023 00:00
0.6
C
0.146119


30/04/2023 00:00
-0.6
C
0.145881



I have tried using .iloc[] but I couldnt get it to work

Create DataFrames:
import pandas as pd

dates = ['27/04/2023 00:00', '28/04/2023 00:00']
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': dates,'A': [55.6, 57.2],'B': [0.31, 0.32]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': dates*2, 'change': list('zxcv'),'Ticker': list('AABB')})

Actual soulton:
df3 = pd.melt(df1, id_vars=['Date'], value_vars=df2.Ticker.unique(), var_name='Ticker', value_name='Px')
df_out = pd.merge(df2, df3, on=['Date','Ticker'], how='inner')


In the df3 function melt unpivot df1 from wide to long format.

df_out merged df1 and df3 together on columns Date and Ticker.


df1:



Date
A
B




27/04/2023 00:00
55.6
0.31


28/04/2023 00:00
57.2
0.32



df2:



Date
change
Ticker




27/04/2023 00:00
z
A


28/04/2023 00:00
x
A


27/04/2023 00:00
c
B


28/04/2023 00:00
v
B



df3:



Date
Ticker
Px




27/04/2023 00:00
A
55.6


28/04/2023 00:00
A
57.2


27/04/2023 00:00
B
0.31


28/04/2023 00:00
B
0.32



df_out



Date
change
Ticker
Px




27/04/2023 00:00
z
A
55.6


28/04/2023 00:00
x
A
57.2


27/04/2023 00:00
c
B
0.31


28/04/2023 00:00
v
B
0.32




Thank you very much, that solution worked for me.
This is the first time I come across the melt function.

Try the following:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Sample data for df1
data1 = {
    'Date': ['27/04/2023 00:00', '28/04/2023 00:00', '29/04/2023 00:00', '30/04/2023 00:00'],
    'A': [55.66371155, 57.14315796, 57.3841629, 57.12593079],
    'B': [0.321940005, 0.327948987, 0.322167009, 0.320318013],
    'C': [0.145006001, 0.147119999, 0.146118999, 0.145880997]
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])  # Ensure 'Date' is a datetime object

# Sample data for df2
data2 = {
    'Date': ['27/04/2023 00:00', '28/04/2023 00:00', '29/04/2023 00:00', '30/04/2023 00:00'] * 3,
    'change': [0.1, -0.1, 0.2, -0.2, 0.3, -0.3, 0.4, -0.4, 0.5, -0.5, 0.6, -0.6],
    'Ticker': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C']
}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])  # Match the datetime format

# Use numpy to map the values from df1 to df2
ticker_to_col = df1.columns[1:].tolist()  # Skip 'Date' column
df2['Px'] = np.choose(
    np.searchsorted(ticker_to_col, df2['Ticker']),  # Position of Ticker in columns
    [df1[col].values for col in ticker_to_col]  # Values of each column as choices
)

print(df2)

Explanation:

Datetime Conversion:
We start by making sure the 'Date' columns in both dataframes are converted to datetime objects. This helps to ensure that they're properly aligned and can be compared accurately, which is crucial for merging the data correctly.
Mapping with NumPy:
To link the values from df1 to df2 based on the Ticker, we utilize two functions from NumPy: np.searchsorted and np.choose. The np.searchsorted function is used to find the correct column index in df1 for each Ticker in df2. Essentially, it tells us where each Ticker would fit in an ordered list of the column headers from df1. Once we have these indices, np.choose comes into play. It takes these indices and uses them to select the corresponding values from df1 for each row in df2. This way, each Ticker gets the right value from its respective date.

